# Forms in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi-7

There are 2 codes in Delphi 7. I need to make forms for them so that all variables are written to the form by the crawler himself, and not by the programmer through the code.

I tried to create a form from scratch. I tried to build it on a ready-made code. Unfortunately, my knowledge of programming in Delphi 7 is too small to understand the documentation for forms written in a rather complex language.

FIRST:

```pascal
program p1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Math, Windows;

var
  x, z: integer;
var
  RES,s, sp, p, ps, y: real;

begin
  SetConsoleCP(1251);
  SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
  x := 1;
  y := 2.25;
  z := 3;
  ps := 1;
  for x := 1 to 7 do
  begin
    sp := 0;
    for z := 3 to 10 do
    begin
      s := Arctan(y / z + x / y) / power(abs(y - x - z), 1 / 3);
      sp := sp + s;
      //Writeln('Сумма ', sp:0:3);
    end;
    p := (power(2.3, 4 / x) * abs(y - x)) / (sqrt(sqr(x) + sqr(y) + 1.5)) + sp;
    ps := ps * p;
    //Writeln('Произведение ', ps:0:3);
  end;
  RES := ps;
  Writeln(RES:0:3);
  Readln;
end.
```

SECOND:

```pascal
program p2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Math, Windows;

const
  H = 0.4;
  Xmin = -3;
  Xmax = 2.9;

var
  x, y, W: real;

begin
  SetConsoleCP(1251);
  SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
  x := Xmin;
  while (x < Xmax) do
  begin
    if (x > 0.1) and (x < 2) then begin
      W := power(x, 1 / 3) + ln(x);
      y := ((ln(sqr(W) + W + 1)) * cos(4 * x)) / (exp(-2) + 2);
    end
    else if (x <= 0.1) then begin
      W := sqr(sin(x)) + 4 * x;
      y := ((ln(sqr(W) + W + 1)) * cos(4 * x)) / (exp(-2) + 2);
    end
    else begin
      W := 2.6 * sqr(x) - 3.7;
      y := ((ln(sqr(W) + W + 1)) * cos(4 * x)) / (exp(-2) + 2);
    end;
    x := x + H;
    Write('X= ', x:0:3);
    Write('     ');
    Writeln('Y= ', y:0:3);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question

Answer (score -1):

File > New > Forms Application

That will create a new GUI (not Console) project with a blank Form. Design the Form with UI controls and event handlers as needed, and then copy/paste your code above into the generated code as needed.